# MySQL query: find in which range quantity resides and then get the price of max quantity in the range

Tags: mysql

Need a help in building query. I have quantity_price table, listing quantity and corresponding price as shown below

```
Quantity  Price
----------------
1   --  € 175,35
2.5 --  € 160,65
5   --  € 149,10
10  --  € 143,85
```

so for upto 1 quantity price will be 175,35 up to 2.5 it will be 160,65 and so on. For more than 10 quantity, price'll remain to 143,85.

Now if my quantity is 1.5 then query should return price 160,65, which means that find in which range quantity resides and then get the price of max quantity in the range.

Comment: Do you want to do this is MySQL or PHP?

Comment: So why did you tag this question as PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `where` statement to find all rows bigger than 1.5; then use `limit` and `order by` to grab the row with the lowest quantity.  As Petah commented, it's handy to always include the row with the largest quantity.  For example:

```
select  *
from    quantity_price
where   Quantity > 1.5
        or Quantity = (select max(Quantity) from quantity_price)
order by
        Quantity
limit   1
```

Comment: This fails if the quantity if more than 10

Answer (score 1):

```
select price
from quantity_price
where myquantity >= quantity
order by quantity
limit 1
```

Comment: Shouldn't this be `order by quantity ASC` ?

Comment: shoudn't this be `<=` (or `quantity >= myquantity`) ... and it doesn't work for `myquantity` over 10 ?